# How to make a sentence in Python?

Tags: python, join, python-3.x, ascii

Im using Python 3.2 on Win7. I wrote this using ASCII code:

```
print (''.join((chr(i+22) for i in (50,75,90,90,99))))
print (''.join((chr(j+22) for j in (44,83,92,94,82,78,75,99,11))))
```

which as a result writes:

```
Happy 
Birthday!
```

Now, I'd like to join these two words in one sentence, so it writes:

```
Happy Birthday!
```

It seems like a simple thing to do, but I'm new at Python, so could someone help me? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

```
print (''.join((chr(i+22) for i in (50,75,90,90,99,10,44,83,92,94,82,78,75,99,11))))
```

Answer (score 1):

To have them on the same line, and the end of the first print statement, type in the parameter end=" ", so the next print statement will print on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

its simple.. just use `+` operator.

```
print (''.join((chr(i+22) for i in (50,75,90,90,99))))+" "+ (''.join((chr(j+22) for j in (44,83,92,94,82,78,75,99,11))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask `print()` not to add a newline:

```
print(..., end='')
```

`end`, by default, is set to `\n`.

For your sample, that'd be:

```
print(''.join((chr(i+22) for i in (50,75,90,90,99))), end=' ')
print(''.join((chr(j+22) for j in (44,83,92,94,82,78,75,99,11))))
```

printing a space instead of a newline after `Happy`.

You could also include the space in your list of ASCII codepoints; ASCII space is `32`, but you add `22` to your values, so including `10` should do it:

```
print(''.join((chr(i+22) for i in (50,75,90,90,99,10,44,83,92,94,82,78,75,99,11))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Print your output using string formatting:

```
s1 = ''.join((chr(i+22) for i in (50,75,90,90,99)))
s2 = ''.join((chr(j+22) for j in (44,83,92,94,82,78,75,99,11))))

print("%s %s" % (s1, s2))
```